# Group by/ Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'accnt' : [101, 102, 103, 104, 101, 102, 103, 104, 101, 102, 103, 104, 101, 102, 103, 104, 101, 102, 103, 104],
    'value' : [10, 20, 30, 40, 5, 2, 6, 48, 22, 23, 24, 25, 18, 25, 26, 14, 78, 72, 54, 6],
    'category' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,3,2,3]
})
```

dummy_df

```
accnt   value   category
 101     10      1
 102     20      1
 103     30      1
 104     40      1
 101     5       2
 102     2       2
 103     6       2
 104     48      2
 101     22      1
 102     23      1
 103     24      2
 104     25      2
 101     18      3
 102     25      3
 103     26      3
 104     14      3
 101     78      1
 102     72      3
 103     54      2
 104     6       3
```

I want to get a dataframe like below:

```
accnt   sum_val_c1  count_c1    sum_val_ct2 count_c2    sum_val_c3  count_c3
  101       110        3           5           1              18     1
  102       43         2           2           1              97     2
  103       30         1           84          3              26     1
  104       40         1           73          2              20     2
```

Which is summing up the occurrence of a category into `count_c#` and summing the value of that category into `sum_val_c#` and grouping by on `accnt`. I have tried using `pivot()` and `groupby()` but I know I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `agg`, and `unstack`:

```
u = df.groupby(['accnt', 'category'])['value'].agg(['sum', 'count']).unstack(1)
u.columns = u.columns.map('{0[0]}_c{0[1]}'.format)
u

       sum_c1  sum_c2  sum_c3  count_c1  count_c2  count_c3
accnt                                                      
101       110       5      18         3         1         1
102        43       2      97         2         1         2
103        30      84      26         1         3         1
104        40      73      20         1         2         2
```

---

Similarly, with `pivot_table`,

```
u = df.pivot_table(index=['accnt'], 
                   columns='category', 
                   values='value', 
                   aggfunc=['sum', 'count'])
u.columns = u.columns.map('{0[0]}_c{0[1]}'.format)
u

       sum_c1  sum_c2  sum_c3  count_c1  count_c2  count_c3
accnt                                                      
101       110       5      18         3         1         1
102        43       2      97         2         1         2
103        30      84      26         1         3         1
104        40      73      20         1         2         2
```

Comment: This works! But I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav Let me know what was not clear. I think if you run the commands one by one and see how the data is transformed between steps, it'll become clear.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but could you explain unstack and how the map function works for this problem (no rush take your time) ? Looks really useful!

Comment: @Datanovice No worries. The outputs from the first statement (in both options) returns a result with a multi-index column. I then used this neat trick I learned (from Andy? Scott...?) which leverages [`MultiIndex.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.map.html) to flatten the columns by joining them by underscore. Note: This is possible because each multiIndex is internally represented by a list of tuples (do `u.columns.values` after step #1 to see what I mean).

Comment: Thanks that's really clear, will give this a go when I'm at my laptop

Comment: @coldspeed: `MultiIndex.map` is indeed very neat. However, I couldn't find it anywhere in the 0.24.2 docs. There is only `Index.map` in 0.24.2 docs. Is it deprecated in 0.24.2?

Comment: @andy Odd... I don't believe it is deprecated, but I can't seem to find a v0.24 link. Perhaps they did not make one for whatever reasons. If you want still to look at the spec, run `help(pd.MultiIndex.map)` on a python/IPython REPL.

Comment: @coldspeed: it is also odd that `pd.MultiIndex.map` and `pd.Index.map` return the same `<function pandas.core.indexes.base.Index.map(self, mapper)>` and help(...) of both return the same info. So, are they wrapper/decorator of `base.Index.map` ?

Comment: thanks, the tip was super useful, will be using the map with multiindex going forward. p.s i think `u = pd.crosstab(df.accnt,df.category,values=df.value,aggfunc=('sum','count'))` is easier to read, although I may be wrong!

Comment: @Datanovice You are probably correct. I happened to go with pivot_table since that was the titular function in this post (plus, it is usually faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a method to do that.

```
pivot2 = dummy_df.pivot_table(values='value', index='accnt', columns='category', aggfunc=['count', 'sum'])
```

That returns a dataframe like this:

```
         count        sum
category     1  2  3    1   2   3
accnt
101          3  1  1  110   5  18
102          2  1  2   43   2  97
103          1  3  1   30  84  26
104          1  2  2   40  73  20
```

Comment: Sorry, just thought I should point out I have covered this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55621820/4909087).

Comment: @coldspeed There is nothing wrong if inadvertently people end up posting similar answers. Posting multiple methods should not in any way preclude others from answering with one of the methods if they are already in the process of composing an answer.

Comment: Sorry @coldspeed. I couldn't read the question page before I sent my answer after I start to write it.